# HDD spindown despite disabled powersave

Tags: linux, hard-drive, powersave

recently I discovered that my HDD spins down quite frequently. As far as I can say, this is a new behaviour. I fear hardware damage from frequent spin down / spin up sequences (can this happen?).
I am running linux 5.15.8-1-default and tried changing the powersaving options with hdparm - which was the only solution I found on the internet:

```
hdparm -S 255 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting standby to 255 (21 minutes + 15 seconds)
```

and

```
hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to disabled
 APM_level      = off
```

still, the HDD spins-down quite often after only few seconds, e.g.:

```
dmesg -T |grep sda

[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5
[So Jan  2 09:31:39 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[So Jan  2 09:31:45 2022] EXT4-fs (sda4): recovery complete
[So Jan  2 09:31:45 2022] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[So Jan  2 09:37:59 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 09:37:59 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[So Jan  2 09:38:02 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[So Jan  2 09:42:59 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 09:42:59 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[So Jan  2 09:52:00 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[So Jan  2 09:52:35 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 09:52:35 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[So Jan  2 09:53:01 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[So Jan  2 09:53:38 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 09:53:38 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[So Jan  2 10:01:54 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[So Jan  2 10:02:18 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 10:02:18 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[So Jan  2 10:12:00 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[So Jan  2 10:12:20 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[So Jan  2 10:12:20 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
```

between issuing the hdparm commands and dmesg was **no** reboot.
I am aware of this topic being treated quite often but usually people are successful using hdparm and I could not find out why this did not happend in past. So my questions are:

1. Is repeated spin down and spin up really harmful to the hardware?
2. Can the change in behaviour come from a) software updates or b) aged hardware?
3. Is there a solution that I just did not find? How can I make the drive stay on for a longer time?

Already in the past I found some devices that did ignore hdparm settings but what seems really strange is that this drive or my system now changed its behaviour.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What’s the brand and model of the hdd?

Comment: it is a seagate ST1000LM035-1RK172

Answer (score 0):

It’s tlp.service responsible for this issue as it enables ALPM (AHCI link power management) and AHCI Runtime PM on BAT which causes this start / stop / start / stop of hdd/ssd.

To disable: in /etc/tlp.conf (or /etc/default/tlp.conf for older versions), uncomment:

```
SATA_LINKPWR_DENYLIST="hostX"
```

Refer to the output of tlp-stat -d to determine the host, replace ‘X’ accordingly.
uncomment and set to ‘on’ (means ‘disable’)

```
AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on
```

You have to power cycle to make the settings take affect - not only reset!

Verify with powertop - tab ‘adjustable setting’ should show:

```
bad  Runtime PM for disk sda
bad  Runtime PM for port ata1 of PCI device: [your specific vendor device e.g. Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor N3XXX Series]
bad  Runtime PM for port ata2 of PCI device: [your specific vendor device e.g. Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor N3XXX Series]
```

Watch ‘journalctl -f’ to monitor.

[Source](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/hard-drive-hdd-endlessly-cycling-stopping-starting-disk-when-laptop-is-on-battery/87089/7)